# Lua code Editing Fortnite issues with MoveMouseRelative

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

MoveMouseRelative moves very fast but I noticed that when I make my mouse move up then right it often gets a shortcut. So I miss some squares when I edit.
So instead of going up then right it seems to go across.
I tried to add more sleep time in the movemouse or between two moves. In first case it moves too slowly and in the second it stills taking shortcuts.

This code is what is working the best (less worse), I make several up or down movements in order that smaller shortcuts are taken. But I'm sure it can be improved with a more simple code (less lines) and having à good drawing of the edit.

How can that be fixed please?

```
----------------
    -- Boutton 8 edit en rond ou du haut vers le bas mur ou escalier - MB8 round edit or up and down stair and wall             
    ----------------
    -- CapsLock OFF
    -- Edit en rond - Round edit
    
      if not IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
            if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8) then
    
                        PressAndReleaseKey("BackSpace")-- Edit
                        FastSleep(5)
                        PressAndReleaseKey("T")-- Reset Edit
    
                if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    
                        --Regarder - Look
                            for i = 0, 20 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,127) -- bas - down
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
    
                        -- Dessiner Edit - Draw Edit
                            PressKey(13)-- Select Edit
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 4 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 4 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (127,0) -- droite - right
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,127) -- bas - down
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,127) -- bas - down
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (-127,0) -- gauche- left
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (-127,0) -- gauche - left
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,127) -- bas - down
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(1)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (127,0) -- droite- right
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
                end
```

(....)

```
 if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 8 then

                    FastSleep(1)
                    ReleaseKey(13)-- Select Edit
                    FastSleep(1)
                    PressAndReleaseKey("F1")
                    PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                    end
    end
  end
```

Comment: The game usually updates its state (including user input) every frame, and FPS is usually 60.  So, 16 ms per update.  This means sleep of 0.5 ms is pointless here.  You should stay (not move) during 16 ms in each corner before changing direction of moving to avoid shortcuts.

Comment: As I remember I already tried that fastsleep 20 or 30 between each. Over 30 i use sleep as you said in an other question. I will try again by focusing on corners only. But my frame is 144 hz and I turn at 100hz at average.

Comment: @Egor I tried focusing on corners. Seems to be a little better and just very few slower. Both when tested in Creative Mode (low ping <10ms) works almost good. But in game (20-30 ms ping) much more issues. Does all this code depends on ping ? Or I just need to find the good sleep time?

Comment: Probably the game's update time interval depends on ping.

Comment: @Egor yeah probably ping giving issues. I find a way to make corners move without shortcuts (see my answer). I was trying to integrate it to my previous code but suddenly when making my tests nothing worked anymore. Ghub tells me :  [string "LuaVM"]:39: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (local 'ms') Line Number:1 => this in your code for fastsleep . I copy/paste it again from original = the same. Any idea ? Getrunningtime issue ?

Comment: Probably you pass `nil` as argument to FastSleep

Comment: yeah i put  s = 0.5 as comment but was still using fastsleep(s) somewhere. So the corners i managed to code makes it edit a little better but not perfectly. It's only when i raise my fastsleep time thet it goes better in creatif but it still getting issues in game. Still trying things.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a way in order to move for example fast up and slow right then slower up and faster right in order to make à 90° up then right.

I managed to do that and it works quite good :

```
                n = 20
                s = 0.5
                p = 120
                q = 120
                
                for i = 1, n do
                MoveMouseRelative (p/(n-i+1),q/i) -- bas puis droite - down then right
                FastSleep(s)
                end
                
                for i = 1, n do
                MoveMouseRelative (p/i,-q/(n-i+1)) -- droite puis haut - right then up
                FastSleep(s)
                end         
                                        
                for i = 1, n do
                MoveMouseRelative (-p/(n-i+1),-q/i) -- haut puis gauche - up then left
                FastSleep(s)
                end
                
                for i = 1, n do
                MoveMouseRelative (-p/i,q/(n-i+1)) -- gauche puis bas - left then down
                FastSleep(s)
                end
```

This code draws a kind of square with round corners with your mouse moving.

- change n to higher = the rounded corners are less rounded but it get's slower
- change n to less = shortcut is taken between the two ways
- s only changes the fastsleep to see how the drawing is going
- p and q should be less then 120 = change both to 80 = smaller square
  change only one makes a rectangle
- change n, p and q = didn't try yet

Comment: Why not simply stop with `Sleep(30)` when you are on the corner?  I mean insert Sleep between these loops.

Comment: I have already tried a sleep(20) and i tried the sleep(30) => it's a little bit too slow but it could be fine if it worked. It's a mix of raising the fastsleep delay and adding the sleep(20)  or 30 that works the less worse.  In creatif mode (low ping) it works 9 times over 10 but in game it's only 6/10. I hope a solution exists to improve this.

Comment: The other problem is that when I press quickly MB8 to edit and MB4 to 6 to build in some case (pressed and released very fast MB8 then MB4to6) my resolution still stuck in high dpi and nothing in my code can explain this. It looks like the edit code interrupt the execution of the build code letting only the first macro being executed but not the whole script (nothing is built) !!! Any idea @Egor cause u know my both questions (codes) ?

Comment: `my resolution still stuck in high dpi and nothing in my code can explain this.`  - The code you posted in the question does nothing with DPI.  So, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: At the beguining I posted my whole code with in one question and I was asked to post each piece of code with a question for each issue. You replied me to my other question (build with lua in fortnite) and solved my problem. This other code (in the same lua script) uses macros to up and low dpi. But when others MB pressed at the the same time with this MB8 very quickly I still stuck in high resolution dpi. That's it.

Comment: The other code ==> if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and (arg == 4 or arg == 5 or arg == 6) then
   (...)
       if MB4 or MB5 or MB6 then
          PlayMacro("PlusReso")
        repeat
           (...)
          until not (MB4 or MB5 or MB6)
          (....)  PlayMacro("MoinsReso")
       end
    end

Comment: Inserting `Sleep(100)` before and/or after `PlayMacro` might help.  If that does not help, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Ok i'll try that but i can imagine that it will introduce à little delay before building and decrease the speed of building the first wall ... wich we'll be anoying too. Thanks Egor. I'll put a comment here when it's done.

Comment: Insert it before and after last wall.

Comment: Nothing really works. More sleep before or after makes it quite slower without really improving it. This seams to be very depending on ping/fps. Keap trying things, hope one day i'll found how to make that works perfectly.